# how to find the max value in the table, if there is the same value, then retrieve data from the smallest ID among the data found (mysql 5.5.36)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, with names of **identities** and **results**.
I want to retrieve all data, based on the **rs_val** column which has the maximum value, then group data by column **identities.idn_year** and **identities.idn_tag**

if there is the same maximum value, then the data displayed is based on the smallest **rs_id** among the same data, but different data years and tags are still displayed

```
**Table identities**
idn_kode | idn_name | idn_year | idn_tag 
IDN.001    Andi       2017         3
IDN.002    sarah      2017         3
IDN.003    Jhon       2017         3
IDN.004    Doe        2018         5
IDN.005    Mark       2018         5
IDN.006    Sisca      2018         5

**Table result**
rs_kode  |  idn_kode  |  rs_id   |  rs_val
RS.001      IDN.002       2          73
RS.002      IDN.004       4          90
RS.003      IDN.005       5          90
RS.004      IDN.006       6          85
RS.005      IDN.003       3          100
RS.006      IDN.001       1          65
```

**I tried using this query**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM result ORDER BY rs_val DESC ) x INNER JOIN identities a on x.idn_kode = a.idn_kode GROUP BY a.idn_yer, a.idn_tag


**the results of the query above**
idn_name | idn_year | idn_tag  | id  | rs_val
Jhon         2017        3        3     100
Mark         2018        5        5      90
```

**Expected results**

```
idn_name | idn_year | idn_tag  | rs_id  | rs_val
Doe          2018        5         4       90
Jhon         2017        3         3       100
```

please, is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with cte as (
  select i.idn_name, i.idn_year, i.idn_tag, r.rs_id, r.rs_val, 
    row_number() over (partition by i.idn_year, i.idn_tag order by r.rs_val desc, r.rs_id) rn
  from identities i inner join result r
  on r.idn_kode = i.idn_kode
)  
select idn_name, idn_year, idn_tag, rs_id, rs_val
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qty3hhVpGN3wTRp1ojST2/2).
Results:

```
| idn_name | idn_year | idn_tag | rs_id | rs_val |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ----- | ------ |
| Jhon     | 2017     | 3       | 3     | 100    |
| Doe      | 2018     | 5       | 4     | 90     |
```

For MySql 5.5 use this query:

```
select i.idn_name, i.idn_year, i.idn_tag, min(r.rs_id) rs_id, t.val 
from identities i 
inner join result r on r.idn_kode = i.idn_kode
inner join (
  select i.idn_year, i.idn_tag, max(r.rs_val) val 
  from identities i inner join result r
  on r.idn_kode = i.idn_kode
  group by i.idn_year, i.idn_tag
) t on t.idn_year = i.idn_year and t.idn_tag = i.idn_tag and t.val = r.rs_val 
group by i.idn_year, i.idn_tag, t.val
```

For this code to work you must have `[ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY][2]` SQL mode disabled.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgf1jxoiqEMXB4DjhmTyZ2/1).

Comment: Thank for your answer. the other problem
I am using mysql version : 5.5.36 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)  :(

Comment: thank you so much sir for your help.
very helpful.

query is work :)